# Cannot install my own Facebook app

Tags: facebook

I haven't done a Facebook app in a while. Today I needed to create a simple application for a customer and I'm still not able to install it.

The app is very basic. The idea is to have an extra "tab" where the app will simply show a jpg stored on an external server.

The main problem at this moment is that when I login as the clients page admin, and navigate to the app page, it does not show the "add app to page" link.

How can I install my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieve your app id from https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Replace your app id in the following URL where it says YOUR_APP_ID:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=http://facebook.com